# Python Entry Widget data auto update and save in a text file

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a text file which contains four words line by line. suppose for example:

```
cat
mat
rat
hat
```

I want to show these words in an Entry widget. Like "cat" in first Entry widget, "mat" in second Entry widget and so on so. Now, if I update the contents of any Entry widget then it should also auto update in the text file. I wrote some codes to display Entry widgets but after that am not getting how to achieve this?

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()

with open('C:/Users/jaykr/Desktop/data.txt') as file:
    data = file.read().split("\n")

for i in range(len(data)):
    Entry(top).grid(row=i, column=0)

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of tkinter's `StringVar` [variable class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and its `trace()` method. Here is an MCVE:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry_var = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=10, textvariable=entry_var)
entry.pack()

def autoupdate(*args):
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(entry_var.get())

entry_var.trace('w', autoupdate)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mentalita . It's working for only one Entry widget but, i want for more than 4 entry widgets and the data should also display in all widgets. So, request you to please update the code for more entry widgers.

Comment: @MritunjayKumarjaykr: you cannot 'request' that I write your code for you. I'm afraid you'll have to do it yourself. I have already given you an example how can you do what you want to do, which is more than enough to get you started.

Comment: ok @mentalita , let me try. Actually, the main problem is that how to make relationship between line of text file and entry widget numbers. suppose i edit some text in 3rd entry widget than the 3rd line of text file should be update.